# How to obtain UCM stream and baseline with cleartool?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

For build logging, I need to obtain the current stream/baseline with `cleartool`, but I am stuck in determining which command will give me this information.

How can I make `cleartool` tell me which stream/baseline I am currently looking at? It is no problem if the output needs preprocessing or filtering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are in a view, you can:

- get the current stream

```
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

- get all baselines for a component in that stream

```
cleartool lsbl -comp myComp@\myPVob -stream myStream@\myPVob
```

- get all foundation baselines for that stream

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" stream:myStream@\myPVob
```

Don't forget that in a view on a stream with a *modifiable* component, what you see is not just a baseline, but a (foundation) baseline plus all the modifications done in the branch associated with said stream.

Comment: Thanks. Number 1 is exactly what I was looking for. I can see that "cleartool lsbl -cview" tells me the names of the baselnies attached to my view, so I can just do a sort and then know which was the latest. Now, I just need to know if the stream was modified after the baseline was applied, but I will ask that in a separate question.

Comment: @Christian: I have the answer to your second question ready to be posted. Only your question on SO is missing ;)

Comment: thank you for being thorough and including this one: get all foundation baselines for that stream : )

Comment: Is there any command to find foundation baseline of a component as per stream?