# How to make cleartool tell if source is modified since last baseline

Tags: build-automation, clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

For build logging, I am able to obtain the current stream and last baseline by means of cleartool (as detailed in "[How to obtain `UCM` stream and baseline with cleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439292/howto-obtain-ucm-stream-and-baseline-with-cleartool)").
But this is only unambiguous if I can also tell that no changes were made since the last baseline.

So: how can I make cleartool tell me if changes have been applied since the last baseline?

Bonus question: does ClearCase terminology have a name for this (whether or not the baseline is "untouched")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if a stream has any modification since the latest baseline (meaning that stream has at least one modifiable component), you can:

- get the latest baseline date for the current view

```
cleartool lsbl -fmt "%d\n" -cview
```

(the last one is the most recent)
- do a find for any new version since that date

```
cleartool lsbl -fmt "%d\n" -cview
2008-05-29T16:40:28+02:00
[...]
2009-09-27T09:51:28+02:00

cleartool find . -ver "brtype(MyProject_Dev) && created_since(2009-09-27T
09:51:28+02:00)" -print
.@@\main\MyProject_Int\MyProject_Dev\3
.\.checkstyle@@\main\MyProject_Dev\CHECKEDOUT
.\.classpath@@\main\MyProject_Int\MyProject_Dev\1
.\.classpath@@\main\MyProject_Int\MyProject_Dev\CHECKEDOUT
[...]
```

There is no special terminology for an untouched baseline, because a baseline is by definition "untouched" (you can never modified or change the content of a baseline).

A stream can have modifications only if there are non-empty activities which shows that at least one version has been created.

Comment: Thanks VonC. This is what I needed. I was hoping that I could find "files that are either checked out or checked in since the baseline was applied" on "version tree perspective" instead of "time perspective", but it will definitely suffice and tell me whether I am looking at the baseline or the baseline plus modifications.

Comment: @Christian: but find request will precisely list you all the versions of files modified since last baseline. Do you need just the files, without their versions?