# Find if current stream contains baseline in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

Let us say I have a baseline called A1. What I then want to see if there is any way for me to be on another stream, anywhere in the same project, to see if I have A1 in my stream? I.e. do I have the code changes made in A1 in my stream?

Is there any fast way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ClearCase works based on activities, and you should determine is an activity has been delivered by using `cleartool lsact -contrib`:
See "[Activities delivered since the last baseline](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21136012)", and a more complete example at "[Describe baseline and expand deliver and rebase activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327917/describe-baseline-and-expand-deliver-and-rebase-activities)".

You can list all activities of a baseline with `cleartool descr -l baseline:A1@\pvob`.

---

Another case is simply when `A1` is a foundation baseline in your other stream.
you can describe your other stream, using [`fmt_ccase` format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), to list only the foundation baselines and check if `A1` is part of those.
See "[Display Current Baseline with Cleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898359/6309)".

Then you need to check if you have LATEST versions which have no 'A1' label on them.
See for instance "[How to make cleartool tell if source is modified since last baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447668/6309)".