# Finding ClearCase activities with certain attributes

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

Anybody have any idea how I can do a search for activities that have certain attributes in ClearCase UCM (v8) on Windows?

I have tried various permutations of "cleartool find" but everytime I run it I find nothing (or it runs far too long and I have to kill it).

I've tried something like this:

```
cleartool find . -elem "attype_sub(MyAttributeName)"  -print
```

to no avail as it seems to run forever. I tried it from the root of the code in my snapshot view. There is an activity in that view with the correct attribute.

If you know how I can do this in the GUI too, feel free to throw that in too. I believe you can do it through the Report Viewer, but again that search came back empty too.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "one command only" rcleartool which would search directly for attributes on activities.

For activity, the surest way to search for them is to use [`cleartool lsact`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm).

You can filter them by stream and by component, and you can filter the output in order to select the activity you want.

Note that with ClearTeam and CC8.0.x, there doesn't seem to be a `lsactivity` in the [`rcleartool commands`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm).
You would have to use a [`rcleartool descr -l`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm), to describe a stream or a baseline ([like in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13565533/6309)) in order to grep for those activities.

**For each activity, again a describe will be necessary on each one to extract their attributes**.