# ClearCase How to make a baseline with specific version of elements

Tags: clearcase

Can I do this in the clearcase UCM environment and how?

1. Current recommended bl is BL_A
2. Lets say I have the following files in the int stream among other files

   a. fileA@@/main/int/22

   b. fileB@@/main/int/17

   c. fileC@@/main/int/4
3. create and recommend a baseline BL_B = BL_A + fileA@@/main/int/21 + fileB@@/main/int/13 + fileC@@/main/int/4

The version of file fileA, fileB and fileC in #3 are, ofcourse, greater than the versions in BL_A

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you put a baseline, you are labelling all the currently checked in and selected versions in your UCM view.

You can edit said current UCM view:

```
cd /path/to/my/view
cleartool edcs
```

Add at the beginning selection rules to select the right versions for your files:

```
element /path/to/file/A /main/int/22
element /path/to/file/B /main/int/17
element /path/to/file/C /main/int/4
```

Then put your baseline.

Comment: That is something I was going to explore. Thanks for confirming that it works. Can I label (label_C) the said files with the specific version and do BL_B = BL_A + label_C ?

Comment: @user3528130 putting a baseline means referencing *all* the versions selected, which here would be `BL_A` + the newest versions. If you put an incremental baseline first, only `A`, `B` and `C` will receive an actual label, which can help you put another (self-made) label (a `cleartool find` can help search for versions with a label corresponding to the incremental baseline you just put, and to your "`label_C`"). Then you can promote your incremental baseline into a full one, which will represent `BL_A` + `label_C`.

Comment: BTW, in my conf_spec (cs), I should be able to point to any version of the files and make the baseline right? In your reply, you point to the top and that is not something I want o do.

Comment: @user3528130 yes, you can reference any version, *but* your selection rules must be *before* the other UCM-generated rules. Or they would be ignored.

Comment: I understand. It applies the first rule it encounters for an element.

Comment: I tried the cs way of creating a baseline. However, there seems to be a problem. I have a makefile set to point to version /main/int/26. the top of the stream is /main/int/27. Now I make a baseline. Then I change view to my development view and rebase of this new baseline. However, it brings /main/int/27 to my view rather than the /main/int/26.

Comment: For the label, I actually meant creating a label (mklbtype, mklabel) with these versions of the files. Then doing "ct mkbl -import <label>"

Comment: @user3528130 Then you would need to that label to be put on *all* the files of your component. But in that case, you don't even need a label: simply put a *full* baseline, and that will be enough. And change you config spec to select your makefile at the right version when you put said full baseline.

Comment: Looks like I am slave to UCM. It always puts the baseline on the top of the integration stream. None of the above seems to work. I will do more experiments. BTW, I am working on the dynamic views. Is snapshot view any better or different?

Comment: @user3528130 no dynmic view are fine: but you need to use the UCM view attached to the right stream. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309