# How can I find an UCM view on which stream corresponds?

Tags: view, clearcase-ucm

In UCM I have a view A and I want to find out on which UCM stream is created.
How can I find an UCM view on which stream corresponds?

Command "`cleartool lsview -properties -full A`" doesn't tell me anything about the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cd /path/to/my/view
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

That allows you to get other information from that stream, like [foundation baselines or baselines for a component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309).

Adding the `-anc` option, you see where that stream is located:

```
cleartool lsstream -cview -anc
```

With [`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-6-6), you can get its name directly:

```
cleartool lsstream -fmt "%n" -cview
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I already tried "cleartool lsstream ...." but is not working on a view created by another user. If I try the command on a view created by me it works.

Comment: @AlexM what error message do you get? It shouldn't matter that the view is not created by you. `cleartool lsstream -view anotherView` doesn't work?