# How to find all ClearCase projects using a particular component

Tags: clearcase-ucm

The only way I found how to find all ClearCase projects that use a particular component is the following:

Get a list of all the projects' Integration streams:

```
cleartool lsproj -fmt %[istream]Xp -invob <pvob>
```

For each Integration stream found, get a list of foundation baselines:

```
cleartool lsstream -fmt %[found_bls]CXp <stream>
```

For each foundation baseline found, check if the component appears in the output:

```
cleartool descr baseline:<baseline> | find "component: <component>"
```

This works perfectly but really looks like a roundabout way to do it. Anyone know of a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty much the usual way to explore those UCM projects.
I used a similar way in "[How to obtain UCM stream and baseline with cleartool?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309)"

Maybe a [`cleartool lsstream --tree`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstream.htm) allows you to get all the streams directly, instead of querying stream by stream.