# How can I obtain foundation baseline for a component?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have used below command but it provides all foundation baselines.

```
 cleartool descr -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" stream:myStream@\myPVob
```

Is there any way to get foundation baseline of a single component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned before [how to get the foundation baselines for a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309).

But [`fmt_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) does not include foundation baselines for a component.
The only two directives appplied to an UCM component are:

- `%[initial_bl]Xp`: Initial baseline of the component
- `%[root_dir]p`: The root directory for the component

So you have two options:

- `%[component]Xp` (for an UCM baseline), for describing each baseline you get from `%[found_bls]CX`, getting each component name that way.
  Once you get the expected component name, you know its baseline
- %[components]CXp (for an UCM stream), listing the components for which the stream has foundation baselines.

If the second option (%[components]CXp), applied to a stream, lists the component in the same order than it list baselines with `%[found_bls]CXp` (for a stream), then it would be quicker (the baseline for the third component would be the third baseline listed by `%[found_bls]CXp`)

But if the order is not the same, then you must loop on each baseline from  `%[found_bls]CXp`, and describe each of them with `%[component]Xp`, until you get the component you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Components don't have "foundation" baselines. The concept of a "foundation" baseline only applies to streams. So, you will need to check this on a per-stream basis.

Complicating this further is the concept of "composite baselines" which are themselves a collection of baselines (and these can be nested).

Off the top of my head, you would start by looking at either the foundation or recommended baselines of integration streams, and breaking that down by component (including by drilling down into composite baselines). Unless the integration streams are very new, the "recommended" baseline may be more useful than the foundations.

Comment: I never used *nested* composite baselines, because of "parasite" baselines (especially on rooted components vs. rootless components), that I presented in 2006 in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013798284 (search for the word "parasite")